# How to position an object in 3d space according to a 2d screen position?

Tags: javascript, project

There are several topics on how to get the 2d screen position of a 3d object in 3d space.

I was wondering how it works the other way around:

How can I get a position in 3d space according to a 2d position?

For example, how can I position a 3D object on the windows upper left corner?

So far I tried it like this:

https://github.com/cheesyeyes/19603.2d.screen.position/blob/master/src/index.js

https://cheesyeyes.github.io/19603.2d.screen.position/

```
function positionOnScreen(vector, object){

raycaster.setFromCamera( vector, camera );

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);

if(intersects.length>0){
  object.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
 }
}

positionOnScreen(new Vector2(.8,.8), mesh1);
```

I am sending rays to a plane that is parallel to the screen, but I am pretty sure there must be a better way..

Comment: Read your question again and imagine how much sense it is making to the reader. If you want a good answer you need to ask a good question.

Comment: A window is a 2D surface, so what does it have to do with a 3D position??

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. I am talking about a threejs webgl project. if you project a 3d space on a 2d screen every object has a position in (projected) 3d space.

Comment: @cheesyeyes, there are _many_ positions in 3D space that would position an object at the upper-left corner of a window on the user's 2D screen. (Mathematically, this number is infinite.) What is your actual goal here?

Comment: Okey, I'll try to start over again ;)